# jQuery not working after using renatomarinho / laravel-page-speed package?

Tags: laravel

I wanted to minify html output so I have used the renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed package. I have done as per the instruction on its github page `https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed`. But for some reason now the jquery stopped working after installing this package. I thought this issue was caused due to the comments in javascript file so i have removed all the comments from the js library files that I have included. But still jquery is not working. Please help me out. Please check the attached image.

[image: error image]

**javascript code**

```
<script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js') }}?v={{ time() }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js') }}?v={{ time() }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js') }}?v={{ time() }}"></script>
<!--end::Global Theme Bundle-->
<!--begin::Page Scripts(used by this page)-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $("#loginform").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var status=false;
        
            if($(".email").val()==""){
                $(".email_error").html("Email address is mandatory");
                $(".email_error").show();
                status=false;
            } else {
                $(".email_error").hide();
                status=true;
            }

            if($(".email").val()!==""){
                if(validateEmail($(".email").val())==false){
                    $(".email_error").html("Invalid Email address");
                    $(".email_error").show();
                    status=false;
                } else {
                    $(".email_error").hide();
                    status=true;
                }
            }

            if($(".password").val()==""){
                $(".password_error").html("Password is mandatory");
                $(".password_error").show();
                status=false;
            } else {
                $(".password_error").hide();
                status=true;
            }

            if(status==true){
                var formdata=$("#loginform").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('admin.loginprocess') }}",
                    type:"post",
                    async:false,
                    data:formdata,
                    success:function(res){
                        if(res.status=='fail'){
                            $(".alert-danger").html("Invalid email or password");
                            $(".alert-danger").removeClass('d-none');
                            $(".alert-success").addClass('d-none');
                       }
                       if(res.status=='success'){
                            $(".alert-success").html("Login Successful");
                            $(".alert-success").removeClass('d-none');
                            $(".alert-danger").addClass('d-none');
                            setTimeout(function(){ window.location="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}"; }, 1500);
                       }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function validateEmail(email) {
        const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

when load your .js, you have to set this attribute to load first and resolve the problem

**data-pagespeed-no-defer**

like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"  data-pagespeed-no-defer></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

- open : App/Http/Kernel.php
- coment : /RenatoMarinho\LaravelPageSpeed\Middleware\DeferJavascript::class,

work for me.

Comment: Please have a read of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer, and also check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.